# PLSQL select most occuring value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to do the following: 
Creating a procedure that returns the section_id value with the most amount of enrollments. This can be calculated by counting the amount of student_id's in that table.

Example:

```
SELECT count(student_id) amount
FROM enrollments
WHERE section_id=20;
```

This would return the amount of enrollments for section number 20.

But I want it to return the amount of the section with the most enrollments. But I don't know how, any suggestions on how to solve this? As I mentioned I use PLSQL so all those functions may be used here

Comment: Lookup `group by section_ID`, `order by amount` and `limit/offsets` within oracle.  If you don't have a version that supports limit/offset, look at using rownum

Comment: @xQbert - I wasn't aware of **any** Oracle version that supports `limit/offset` - are you?

Comment: Are you REQUIRED to use pl/sql for this? Or did you use the term without knowing what it means? What it means is a procedural language related to Oracle Database; what you need here is a simple, standard, plain SQL statement, unless somebody asked you specifically to use pl/sql.

Comment: Another question. What if two (or more) sections have the highest enrollment - tied for first place? Do you need to show them all?

Comment: @mathguy: Oracle 12 supports `offset` (but combined with `fetch first` not `limit`)

Comment: I agree with mathguy: it seems strange to look for a stored procedure for this simple problem

Comment: @Mathguy yes there are in [12c Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702)   see the "row_limiting_clause" section.  Limit may have been a bad word choice.  `OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  SELECT section_id, count(student_id) as StudentCount
  FROM enrollments a
  group by section_id
  having count(student_id) = (SELECT max(count(student_id)) 
  FROM enrollments a
  group by section_id);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/24f7c/1

Here's an interesting link on how to use keep and solving the same query:

http://rwijk.blogspot.com/2012/09/keep-clause.html

Comment: Thank you for your response, I get some errors with the first solution though, haven't tried the second as that's not allowed (by my teacher). I should clear some things: There is no value amount, it was just a name I gave to the count(student_id) value. I use PSQL to store that amount into a variable, I just tried to make the querry as simple as possible for everyone here, as it's not really important. I need to select all the sections with the highest amount of enrollments, which is calculated by counting the student_id's per section. I don't know what to put in the inner query(the 20 in ex)

Comment: SELECT section_id, count(student_id) says statement ignored and (SELECT section_id, max(count(student_id) says too many values

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT section_id, count(student_id) amount
FROM enrollments
GROUP BY section_id
```

Comment: The OP wants the one ID that has the highest count. This query will produce something else. -1 as this answer will not help anyone.

Comment: This will open his eyes to the group by so he can find a solution +1

Comment: @mathguy: I was just introducing him the value of the "group by". It may not totally solve his problem but it will lead him into learning the "group by" clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT count(student_id) amount FROM enrollments 
group by section_id
Order by amount desc
limit 1
```

Comment: There is no `LIMIT` clause in Oracle. -1 as this answer will not help anyone.